# How to set permalink structure via functions.php

Tags: theme-development, permalinks, multisite

I'm setting up a Wordpress Network and wanted all new sites to have the same permalink structure (i.e. "/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/"). I'm wondering if this is possible to do via hooks or hacks in functions.php, without having to rely on users to choose that structure.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set the permalink structure by calling on the `set_permalink_structure()` method of the global `$wp_rewrite` object.

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure( '/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/' );
} );
```

Here's a PHP < 5.3 version of the code in case you're getting errors.

```
function reset_permalinks() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure( '/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'reset_permalinks' );
```

Comment: Copying and pasting your code generates an error, but the rationale does the trick! I only wonder if my question / intentions are good practice, though...

Comment: I assume you're running PHP < 5.3, where closures (anonymous functions) were not available, so I've edited my answer to include the old school way. I tested both code in my theme's *functions.php*, so let me know if this works.Another thing I noticed is that I typed `%year&` instead of `%year%`, so fixed that too.

Comment: Tomas, thanks for accepting the answer. Glad to have been of help. As for good practices - I think that if your objective is to enforce and lock such a permalink structure across websites - then that's justifiable; and by 'lock' I mean that code will not allow any changes to the structure via the Admin, if that's fine then I reckon it's totally okay to do this.

Comment: I am running 5.2.17, so that explains it! Second version works out of the box :) Thank you!

Comment: It works but it cause a conflict when admin saves from permalink page (404 on posts). Then when the site loades (proccess init hook) the permalink structure changes again (404 on posts again). using `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();` solves the problem. Bad practice to use it on init and run it every time. Just visiting the permalinks page will do the tricks.

Comment: The whole intention was to disable the permalinks options page, so maybe I can get away with it?

Comment: It should be called on 'after_switch_theme' or on plugin activation and be followed by 'flush_rewrite_rules()'

Comment: There's a ton of places you can hook this to get the results you want

Answer (score 2):

Previous Answer is not working. I have gotten a pure solution. Can use
Use this code. It will work 100%. Thanks

```
/**
 * Rewrite set up, when theme activate i mean
 */
if (isset($_GET['activated']) && is_admin()) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure('/%postname%/');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

/**
* Redirect to Permalink setting Page.
* Otherwise Redirect rule will not work Properly.
*/
function redirect_to_permalink() {

    wp_redirect('options-permalink.php');
}
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'redirect_to_permalink' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function setPermaLink(){
    $ps = '/%category%/%postname%/';
    $permalink_structure = sanitize_option( 'permalink_structure', $ps);
    $blog_prefix = '/blog';
    $prefix = '/index.php';

    if ( ! empty( $permalink_structure ) ) {
        $permalink_structure = preg_replace( '#/+#', '/', '/' . str_replace( '#', '', $permalink_structure ) );
        if ( $prefix && $blog_prefix ) {
            $permalink_structure = $prefix . preg_replace( '#^/?index\.php#', '', $permalink_structure );
        } else {
            $permalink_structure = $blog_prefix . $permalink_structure;
        }
    }

    $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure( $permalink_structure );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

setPermaLink();
```