# Use /prefix/postname as a slug in post_name?

Tags: functions, slug, wp-update-post

I have a custom field that I would like to use as the post's slug. I'm able to get the custom field to be used as the slug for the post but I'm having problems attaching a /prefix/ before the postname.

This is the code I have so far (If you want to use something else, substitute /episode/ with your choice)

```
wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post->ID,'post_name' => 'episode/'. get_post_meta($post->ID,'incr_number', true)));
```

When it's save, the post's slug is domain/episode1 and I'm trying to get /episode/1.

Comment: Slugs can't contain slashes.

Comment: @Milo Can you move your comment as an answer?

Comment: do you want to do this with a custom post type or with the basic posts ?

Comment: On basic posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it turns out you can't use a slash ('/') in the slug but I found a solution from [How to set permalink structure via functions.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31207/how-to-set-permalink-structure-via-functions-php), set the permalink structure in your theme's functions.php file

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure( '/episode/%postname%/' );
} );
```

It will add `/episode/` before the post slug